# Using replace function inside substitute function

Tags: excel, replace, concatenation, excel-formula, substitution

I need to remove the commas in the string ", xxxxxx," (cell D4) and am currently already using the formula =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,B4,""),C4,""),E4,"")

Ex.

A4: 134 Main, Burles, NC 28817

B4: 28817

C4: 134 Main

D4: i have parsed the data into the above formula, yielding the result ", Burles,"

I've tried concatentate adding the replace function and nothing happens.  The result needs to read without spaces or commas!

Help!

Comment: Please tag with the language. This looks like Excel? Also, consider using `<pre>..</pre>` tags to better "lay out" the sample data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end results to be using your example.  `", xxxxxx,"` is confusing.  Also what is `E4`'s part in the formula?

Comment: Sorry, E4 refers to the "state" which i have as NC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,B4,""),C4,""),E4,""),",","")
```

This will remove the commas, as below:

[image]

Comment: Go a step further and append a TRIM(...) to remove extra spaces